# os.path.isfile() returns false for file on network drive

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to test if a file exists on the network drive using os.path.isfile however it returns false even when the file is there. Any ideas why this might be or any other methods I could use to check for this file?

I am using Python2.7 and Windows10

This returns true as it should:

```
import os

if os.path.isfile("C:\test.txt"):
    print "Is File"
else:
    print "Is Not File"
```

This returns false even though the file exists:

```
import os

if os.path.isfile("Q:\test.txt"):
    print "Is File"
else:
    print "Is Not File"
```

Comment: Using raw string: `os.path.isfile(r"Q:\test.txt")`?

Comment: Also returns false

Comment: What does `os.path.exists()` return?

Comment: os.path.exists() returns false too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From python https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html:

> The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for **local paths**

Trying using the full UNC path instead of the mapped drive.

```
import os

if os.path.isfile(r"\\full\uncpath\test.txt"):
    print "Is File"
else:
    print "Is Not File"
```

Comment: @TomCarroll sweet!  Happy I could help you out