# os.path.isfile() returns false for file on linux smb network drive

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, smb, file-exists

My desktop computer is running Linux Mint 19.1. Another computer is running Linux Mint 18.3. Both computers are running Samba. I am trying to have my desktop python code check for a file on the other computer. In the Caja file manager it shows the path as "smb://lenovo2/kwpvr/". I can copy, delete  or rename the file in Caja.

This question was previously asked but the answer only addressed that other operating system (Windows).
[os.path.isfile() returns false for file on network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492524/os-path-isfile-returns-false-for-file-on-network-drive)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
print(os.path.isfile("smb://lenovo2/kwpvr/kwpvr3.db"))  # False
print (os.path.isfile("//lenovo2/kwpvr/kwpvr3.db"))     # False
print (os.path.isfile("smb:\\lenovo2\kwpvr\kwpvr3.db")) # False
print (os.path.isfile("\\lenovo2\kwpvr\kwpvr3.db"))     # False

print (os.path.exists("smb://lenovo2/kwpvr/kwpvr3.db")) # False
print (os.path.exists("//lenovo2/kwpvr/kwpvr3.db"))     # False
print (os.path.exists("smb:\\lenovo2\kwpvr\kwpvr3.db")) # False
print (os.path.exists("\\lenovo2\kwpvr\kwpvr3.db"))     # False
```

os.path.exists() always returns False for any permutation of the file name I can come up with.

Comment: For backslashes don't forget to escape them! E.g. `"\\\\lenovo2\\kwpvr\\kwpvr3.db"`

Comment: Been there, done that. Same result (and I did not get a t-shirt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path` only works for files that can be accessed through the local file system. It does not work with URIs like `smb://` or `https://`.

If you want to make files on network shares available through the local file system on Linux, you have to mount them, e.g:

```
mount -t cifs //host/myshare /mnt/mypath
```

and then use `os.path.exists("/mnt/mypath/hello.txt")`

Alternatively, use a SMB/CIFS API instead of `os.path`.

Comment: Thank thee .... I thought the answer might be something along those lines. Unfortunately it is also more 'user' complicated than I had in mind.