# How to make `os.path.isdir()` work for mapped network drives?

Tags: python, windows, mapped-drive

When I boot my PC, `os.path.isdir("R:\\")` returns `False`, where `R:\` is a mapped network drive. Once I access the mapped drive at least once from Windows Explorer, the command works and keeps working until I reboot.

I know that I can get around this using UNC paths but since my code is part of a UI, I can't force the user to not use mapped network drives.

How do I make Python reliably accept mapped network drives?
I thought I might be able to simulate opening the folder from Windows by calling something like `os.system("dir R:\\")` but it did not work. Apparently there is some magic Windows is performing under the hood that I cannot replicate through a `os.system` call.

Here is my call history for reference to what I tried:

```py
os.path.isdir("R:\\")  # False
os.system("dir R:\\")  # 1
os.path.isdir("R:\\")  # False
os.system("net use")  # 0
os.path.isdir("R:\\")  # False

# open R:\ in Windows Explorer

os.path.isdir("R:\\")  # True
```

This question deals with the same problem, but the accepted answer proposes the workaround to use UNC paths, but as explained, that does not fit my use case: [os.path.isfile() returns false for file on network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492524/os-path-isfile-returns-false-for-file-on-network-drive)

Comment: What if you use `os.popen("net use")` after reboot?

Comment: Did you try to open the location from python ? I use this on my side : `subprocess.Popen(["explorer.exe", "/select," + file_path], shell=True)` and it triggers the same that manually launch explorer and go to `file_path` location

Comment: "I have also read:" - and **what did you determine as a result**? If they did not appear to be relevant to the problem, then there is no good reason to mention them. If they solved the problem then there is no reason to ask separately. For anything else, presumably there is something you learned and/or tried as a result of that research. Specifically what did you try; what happened when you tried it; and how is that different from what needs to happen? What did you learn, and how does that appear to fit into the problem as a whole - what remaining thing do you need to know?

Comment: @Cow I did in fact, it did not work. I'll add it to the question

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If you want, I can clarify my conclusions to my research if you find them poorly documented. I understood it was enough to indicate that I in fact did my due diligence before asking.

Comment: We don't ask for due diligence. The point of requesting people to do research before posting **is not** to weed out "lazy" people or to see if someone "deserves" an answer. The point is that research is *necessary to determine the precise question* that needs to be asked - to isolate a proper [mre] for "why did the bad thing happen?" questions, and to specify exact semantics for a "how do I make the good thing happen?" questions. I don't want to see the conclusions of your research. I want *you* to *use* those conclusions to refine the question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Could you explain what you expect of me? You ask me to refine the question, but to me it's pretty straightforward: I have a specific problem. There exist similar questions, one of which seems happy to accept an answer with a workaround that is not useful to my use case. So I formulated a question that asks for a solution to the same problem, but without the workaround. Is your concern that I am asking the same question but with a focus on a specific solution?

Comment: @Tricotou This works, but it opens an explorer window, which would be weird for the user of my UI

Comment: "There exist similar questions, one of which seems happy to accept an answer with a workaround that is not useful to my use case." Then at a minimum, you should: 1) explicitly state what the workaround is and 2) explain why you do not consider it an acceptable solution. (Although in many cases the question would still be considered a duplicate; an answer that doesn't involve the workaround should still go on the original question instead.) And if the *other* similar questions were not helpful, then don't bother mentioning them.

Comment: Please also read: ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think a question is not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok, I will remove the less useful links, I thought I was supposed to mention them so help people who wanted to look into this. I thought my original post was clear about what I meant in contrast to what already exists, but if it was not, then I'll try to improve the question

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Better like this?